# How to secure users in azure

Tags: azure, authentication, ionic-framework, azure-active-directory

I have created an application and I am completely finished. I have a login and sign up where users can create their accounts then go ahead and login. However now I must focus on security. I need to authenticate my users but with my existing table called ClubUser. The problem is I don't wanna use google or Microsoft or twitter. I have been looking into azure active directory but I am confused and I don't understand. It seems there is no way for the azure ad to sign users up, and no way to assign them custom attributes. Also, it says all users must have a Microsoft account and that does not work for my app. I have read the azure docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication

Answer (score 0):

Azure Active Directory is Microsoft’s multi-tenant cloud based directory and identity management service. It doesn't support sign-up to create the accounts by users by default. However you can leverage the [Azure AD Graph REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api) to create accounts in your application.

More detail about Azure AD, you can refer link below:

[What is Azure Active Directory?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-whatis)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store user info completely in your app, then you should continue to do that. Otherwise, if you want to allow sign up and use federated authentication, then Azure AD B2C would work for you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview

You can also add custom attributes for the users via the Graph API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr

*Side note for future*: I recommend focusing on security right from the start. It's harder to add it.